# NSImageCell: Set ToolTip

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nsoutlineview, nsimagecell

I'm trying to show a tooltip on the mouse hover at a NSImageCell. I've tried setting the property on Interface Builder (both on the NSImageCell and the NSTableColumn that contains it) but it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by overriding this method in the controller for my NSOutlineView:

```
- (NSString *)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView toolTipForCell:(NSCell *)cell rect:(NSRectPointer)rect tableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item mouseLocation:(NSPoint)mouseLocation;
```

Answer (score 1):

Neither `NSCell` nor `NSTableColumn` will display tool tips, because neither is a subclass of `NSView`. You will have to set the tool tip on the table view itself.

You can use [`-[NSView addToolTipRect:owner:userData:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000014-BBCHBAHJ) to set a tool tip for a particular area of a view. In combination with [`-[NSTableView frameOfCellAtColumn:row:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000118-frameOfCellAtColumn_row_), you ought to be able to set up a different one for each cell.

Answer (score 1):

In case of `NSTableView` you can use

```
(NSString *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView toolTipForCell:(NSCell *)cell rect:(NSRectPointer)rect tableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row mouseLocation:(NSPoint)mouseLocation;
```